# Pure function that reads from storage, compiler bug?

Tags: solidity, compiler, bug, function, pure

I just came across this while testing around with the Diamond Storage pattern. Here is a 'pure' function that reads from storage. This had me wondering, is there actually any difference between pure and view functions from a compiler pov? Is this bug known?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";
import "forge-std/console.sol";

struct Settings {
    uint256 a;
    uint256 b;
}

contract MyContract {
    Settings settings;

    constructor() {
        getSettingsDS().a = 123;
        getSettingsDS().b = 456;
    }

    function getSettingsDS() internal pure returns (Settings storage s) {
        assembly {
            s.slot := 0xabc
        }
    }

    // // @note this will give a compiler error:
    // // Compiler run failed
    // // error[2527]: TypeError: Function declared as pure, but this expression (potentially) reads from the environment or state and thus requires "view".
    // function getSettings() public pure returns (Settings memory) {
    //     return settings;
    // }

    // @note this won't
    function getSettings() public pure returns (Settings memory) {
        return getSettingsDS();
    }
}

contract TestSettings is Test {
    function test_setUp() public {
        MyContract myContract = new MyContract();

        assertEq(myContract.getSettings().a, 123);
        assertEq(myContract.getSettings().b, 456);
    }
}
```

Comment: One can argue that technically `getSettingsDS` isn't reading storage, it is just returning a numeric value that happens to be a storage slot. On the other hand `getSettings` does read from storage because it is converting to memory. You should report the finding to solidity developers. It should trigger at least a warning.